# Optimal function mapping a subset of the real numbers to a discrete set

Tags: optimization, fitting

I have a big dataset with the following information:

```
Person  | TheoreticalPar | ActualPar | Score
-----------------------------------------
Person1 | 1              | 1.2       | 100  
Person1 | 2              | 1.6       | 90  
Person1 | 3              | 1.7       | 105  
Person2 | ...  
...
```

There are 3 observations for each person, one for every value of $\mathrm{TheoreticalPar} \in \{1,2,3\}$. My goal is to find a map $f : \mathrm{ActualParSet} \subset \mathbb{R^+}  \rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$, mapping any continuous value of $\mathrm{ActualParSet}$ to a value in $\{1,2,3\}$, in such a way that score is maximized. Notice that this function must be the same for all the persons, therefore it won't be the optimal function for each single person, but the optimal function for the collective.
The "score" of the function is valued as the sum of the scores. For example, the score of a function mapping everything to 1 is given by the sum of the scores for each person where $TheoreticalPar$ is 1.

A further step of the question would be adding a property to such function: if $ActualPar1 < ActualPar2 \Rightarrow f(ActualPar1)\leq f(ActualPar2).$

Comment: How is the function you are trying to fit related to the score? For example, how would you know if function mapping everything to 1 would be better/worse than function mapping everything to 2?

Comment: It will be an operation with the scores. Let's say simply the sum of the scores. So in this case, the "score" of the function mapping everything to 1, is the sum of the scores of every person (Person1, Person2, Person3, .. ) where TheoreticalPar is 1.

Comment: @JanKukacka I added a further property of the function, please see the last two lines in the main question.